# Endless return of value

Tags: java, loops

I am still very new to java and have a problem with a loop.

I'm trying to make an object with random values.
When i call the method in my main, it returns endless objects.

```
public class knights{                           

    public double health;
    public weapons weapons;
    public double speed;

    public knights(double health,int weapons, double speed){        
        this.health = health;
        this.weapons = new weapons(weapons);
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public static knights choosePick(){

            knights Pick = new knights((70 + (Math.random() * (130 - 70))),-1,(100 + (Math.random() * (150 - 100))));
            System.out.println("The knight Pick is equipped with " + Pick.weapons.type + ". Its damages are " +Pick.weapons.atk + " It has " + Pick.weapons.acc + " accuracy " + "\n" + "He has " + Pick.health + " Health points" + "\n" + "His speed is " + Pick.speed);
            return choosePick();
     }
}
```

I want to call choosePick

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class main_1vs1 {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


                int knight =0;
                while(knight != 1 && knight !=2) {

                    System.out.println("which knight do you choose? Pick is fast (1), Crock is strong (2). " + "\n" + "Make your choice :" + "\n");
                     knight = sc.nextInt();

                 if (knight==1){
                        knights.choosePick();
                        break;
                    }
                 else if (knight==2){
                        knights.chooseCrock();
                        break;
                 }  

                }
    }
}
```

If i hit 1, it will create endless amount of knight.Pick and show endless amount of stat descripition.

Comment: Since the method `choosePick()` calls itself (last line) you're getting into an infinite loop...

Comment: `choosePick()` should return `Pick`, not return itself.

Comment: As a side note, you should follow Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for your classes, variables, etc. While not a requirement, it does help provide additional information at-a-glance. For example, class `knight` should be `Knight` and variable `Pick` should be `pick`.

Answer (score 2):

Once you reach this statement `knights.choosePick();` , you are trapped inside recursion here

```
public static knights choosePick(){

            knights Pick = new knights((70 + (Math.random() * (130 - 70))),-1,(100 + (Math.random() * (150 - 100))));
            System.out.println("The knight Pick is equipped with " + Pick.weapons.type + ". Its damages are " +Pick.weapons.atk + " It has " + Pick.weapons.acc + " accuracy " + "\n" + "He has " + Pick.health + " Health points" + "\n" + "His speed is " + Pick.speed);
            return choosePick();
          //  ^^^  calling recursion
```

Solution

```
public static knights choosePick(){

            knights Pick = new knights((70 + (Math.random() * (130 - 70))),-1,(100 + (Math.random() * (150 - 100))));
            System.out.println("The knight Pick is equipped with " + Pick.weapons.type + ". Its damages are " +Pick.weapons.atk + " It has " + Pick.weapons.acc + " accuracy " + "\n" + "He has " + Pick.health + " Health points" + "\n" + "His speed is " + Pick.speed);
            return Pick;
       //         ^^^ return object instead of calling this function again
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this behavior because your method `choosePick` ends with `return choosePick()` which means that it calls itself such that it is endless thus you end up with a `StackOverflowError`, simply replace the `return` with

```
return Pick;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `knights` class, method `choosePick`, you should not `return choosePick()` but `return Pick;`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!